# Trying to add two rows in MySQL with the same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that has Auto-increment on the ID field. However I need to create, via php, two rows with the same id.

I've tried using `$last_id = intval(mysql_insert_id());`  But just can't get to set the id on the second row. I am very new to php and SQL has never been my closest friend.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'table name' (name, age, phone) VALUES ({$name}, {$age}, {$phone});"
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Then I would like to run the same insert statement again, maybe with the phone being different, but with the ID being the same.

Comment: Needing two rows with the same ID seems an evidence of some problems in the database design... do you have any control over it? And why do you need these two rows to have the same ID?

Comment: If you have set id to auto increment then it will be primary key which is unique. So you can't create duplicate entry

Comment: Auto increment values (usually used for id's) are unique, which means that you can't have two equal values. If you could have two with the same value, how would you determine which will be referenced, if you need to get/update/delete one of them?

Comment: You can't. Auto-increment means that row is a primary key, so its must be different for each rows

Comment: If there're two or more phones for one user then either concatenate both phones into one string or use normalization with another table for phones.

Comment: Unfortunately, I inherited the table structure and do need the id to clock up, but only for every second one. Yes it is PK, but I overcame that with coupling it with a second field. The id is used in another table.  - Quick description is that I have a number of workouts that need to duplicated but for two different months. PK is id + month

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the auto_increment ID field.  This is a primary key, since any auto_increment field must be defined as the table's primary key and therefore cannot have duplicate records.

What you could do is create and additional field for your "**ID**" field that you want to duplicate and then you can insert normally and leave the auto incrementing field do it's thing.